# ListView only show data when I rotate the phone

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

im starting to follow some readings and examples about using the bluetooth module with Android, basically i want to make a test app that show a list of bonded devices when i start the app, I understand basically all the code I follow to make my test app, but I get stuck because when i run the app this ask for enable the bluetooth and show me nothing, the app only show the list when i rotate the phone. What am I doing wrong? thanks for any help

this is my code in java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView listViewDispositivos;

BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
ArrayList<String> arrayListaConectados = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador;
String infoMac, direccionMac;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listViewDispositivos = findViewById(R.id.listViewDispositivos);

    if(bluetoothAdapter == null){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Dispositivo no disponible", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }
    else if(!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
    }
    else {
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayListaConectados);
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {

            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                arrayListaConectados.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No se encontraron dispositivos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        listViewDispositivos.setAdapter(adaptador);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially Bluetooth is not enabled, and you are using Intent to request bluetooth enable which shows dialog. This would not call the else condition because the bluetooth is off.

So you need to get paired devices in onActivityResult which will be called right after you enable bluetooth.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == 1){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //Bluetooth is enable get paired device list here
        }else {
            //Show Error
        }
    }

}
```